Finding Duals Polygons/Polyhedra in $\mathbb{R}^n$
I am reading lecture notes for a class I am taking, and we are discussing vector space duality. We switched the conversation to dual polyhedra, and I am a little confused on why the following technique of obtaining dual polyhedra/polygons works:
Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a polyhedron containing the origin in its interior (but not on any face). Define the dual of $S$ as
$$S^* = \{\varphi \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^* : \varphi(s) \leq 1 \text{ for all } s \in S\}$$
If we consider a square with vertices $(\pm1,\pm1)$, and you look for linear functionals satisfying $\varphi(\pm1, \pm1) \leq 1$, and then use the definition of a dual basis to find the coefficients of the functionals, you can get the inequality $\pm{a}\pm{b} \leq 1$ where all $\varphi((x,y)) = ax + by$. Graphing the inequality $\pm{a}\pm{b}$ on the plane, you get a diamond square.
$(\pm1,\pm1)$ and rotated square with vertices $(0,\pm1)$ and $(\pm, 0)$" />
